# Reset element's CSS active state on browser back?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When clicked or hovered (e.g. from the 'Contact' page) the following code puts a thick light blue underline bar under a toolbar navigation item (e.g. navigate to 'Dashboard' page). The aspx page then redirects to that dashboard page. However if the user then clicks the Back button on their browser, the Contact page still shows that blue underline bar. How can I reset it so the toolbar item in that case in no longer CSS 'active' and showing the blue underline bar?

```
.dvToolbar2TableSub:hover, active
{
    border-color: #01C0FF;
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: #F1F1F1;
}
```

[image]

EDIT: I've just seen that the behavior didn't occur on desktop Firefox. It was on iPad Chrome that I saw it.

Comment: Does `$("body").click()` work?

Comment: @TahaPaksu Good idea I think but a) I think that would remove default focus from the first textbox on the page and b) Do you know what code I could use so that code would run only if there is a "Back" button event?

Comment: hashchange event might be useful if you are using javascript history.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with aspx, but maybe you must remove class 'active' from the toolbar navigation item manually by javascript? You use jquery for this; just do this when you don't want that thick blue underline:

```
$('.dvToolbar2TableSub').removeClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

**You Can Give It A Try**

```
function selectorHighlight(selector) {
                var highlight = 'dvToolbar2TableSub';
                var currentElement = $(selector).click(function (e) {
                    currentElement.removeClass(highlight);
                    $(this).addClass(highlight);
      }
```